# Query parameter as List

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to have a way access certain query parameters for all of my requests.  An example query would be something like:

```
http://api.mysite.com/accounts/123?include=friends,photos
```

Where I want to get access to the comma separated list of `include` relationships.

---

As far as I could tell, the following doesn't work and will look at the include list as a single string:

```
// routes.txt
GET    /accounts/:id    controllers.AccountsController.get(id: Int, include: Seq[String])
```

---

This is how I am currently doing it, but I was hoping there was a cleaner way.

```
// routes.txt
GET    /accounts/:id    controllers.AccountsController.get(id: Int, include: Option[String])

// AccountsController.scala
def get(id: Int, include: Option[String]) = Action {

    // Convert the option to a set
    val set = if (include.isDefined) include.get.split(",").toSet else Set()

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper way to do it (already supported by Play) would be to use repeated key-values in the query string, i.e.:

```
http://api.mysite.com/accounts/123?include=friends&include=photos
```

That would automatically bind `Seq("friends", "photos")` to `include` in that route. This has the advantage of being able to use commas within keys, and is consistent with the common usage of query string parameters.

Alternatively, you can create a custom `QueryStringBindable[List[String]]` that can handle a comma-separated list. Something like:

```
object QueryStringBinders {

    implicit def listBinder(key: String)(implicit stringBinder: QueryStringBindable[String]) = {
        new QueryStringBindable[List[String]] {
            override def bind(key: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]]): Option[Either[String, List[String]]] =
                stringBinder.bind(key, params).map(_.right.map(_.split(",").toList))

            override def unbind(key: String, strings: List[String]): String =
                s"""$key=${strings.mkString(",")}"""

        }
    }

}
```

Then you would use `PlayKeys.routesImport += "QueryStringBinders._"` within build.sbt to use it (or whatever the fully qualified package name is). Using a `QueryStringBindable` would make the split logic reusable, with minimal boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

As, @m-z said the proper way to use is repeated key-values in query string like: `http://api.mysite.com/accounts/123?include=friends&include=photos`

and in you action you can access query string with `queryString` method as well i.e

your route will look like this:

```
GET    /accounts/:id    controllers.AccountsController.get(id: Int)
```

and in your controller:

```
    // AccountsController.scala

    def get(id: Int) = Action { request =>

       // the `request.queryString` will give you Map[String, Seq[String]] i.e all they keys and their values

         val includes  = request.queryString.getOrElse("include", Nil)
    }
```